# Process name for iOS simulator's apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management, ios-simulator

I would like to see the memory footprint of some of the standard iPhone apps when run in the iOS simulator (for comparison purposes).

Does anyone know what these process show up as in Activity Monitor?  I'm talking about the settings app, contacts app, photos app, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulator apps won't show up as processes in Activity Monitor. The only process you should see is **iOS Simulator**.

[image]

Comment: Ah that's a shame - I noticed my own show up but couldn't find apple's. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Usually process name a name of your app